# Dockerizing Alfresco Community Edition

Tags: docker, alfresco

I have installed alfresco in ubuntu 18.04 using this link https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-alfresco-cms-on-ubuntu-1804/. but now i want build a custom a docker image so that i can customize the source code  later and rebuild the image accordingly how can i do that? I have the working Docker-compose file containing the images from docker-hub but i want to know how the images are build and customize to my own?

Comment: You want to edit the Dockerfile, that is the file which tells docker how to build an image. The dockercompose can either build an image using the Dockerfile, or pull a prebuilt image from a docker registry. If you dont have the Dockerfile, maybe have a look at dockerhub for the image?

Comment: the dockerfile is not visible in docker hub for alfresco-acs community.

Comment: Thats normal that you wont find the dockerfile on docker hub. You will want to find their github page. Maybe the link in the answer from @JeffPots below?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this project on GitHub:
https://github.com/Alfresco/acs-community-packaging

That is what is used to build the Alfresco Docker images.

You might also want to look at the Alfresco SDK, which uses Docker images to deploy and test your customizations and config.